# Why pandas dataframe has automatically a first column of autonumber

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and was checking out Pandas.Dataframe. I realize that always I am creating a dataframe, a first column with no column title is created which is also the index column. For example the following code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
table = OrderedDict((
    ("Item", ['Item0', 'Item0', 'Item1', 'Item1']),
    ('CType',['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver']),
    ('USD',  ['1$', '2$', '3$', '4$']),
    ('EU',   ['1€', '2€', '3€', '4€'])
))
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

Gives the result:

```
    Item    CType   USD     EU
0   Item0   Gold    1$  1€
1   Item0   Bronze  2$  2€
2   Item1   Gold    3$  3€
3   Item1   Silver  4$  4€
```

But the first column is not listed in the columns. Because if I execute `len(df.columns)` I will get 4. Or `print(list(df))` will list: `['Item', 'CType', 'USD', 'EU']`. But if I execute `df.index.values` I will get `[0 1 2 3]`. So, what exactly is the first column and can it be avoided?

Comment: First column should be avoided if write to file by `df = pd.to_csv(file, index=False)`

Comment: But by design each DataFrame have `index`

Comment: According to the [`pandas==0.23.4` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.index.html): `DataFrame.index` _The index (row labels) of the DataFrame._

Comment: As everyone mentioned it is just an index. It is really no different than the row index in excel. If you wish to set a column as the index you can use `df.set_index('column_to_index')`

Comment: And it is not possible to create a dataframe without index?

Comment: @CodePope No, you cannot have a dataframe without an index. It is necessary. Look at the duplicate answer to see why.